# How do I make a new Custom Field Set visible in the Tab Display Style?

Tags: contacts, custom-fields

I have created a new Custom Field Set.  When I set Display Style = Inline, the tab shows as expected.

However, when I set Display Style = Tab, it disappears.  There is no Custom Fields tab either?

How can I make the new Custom Field Set visible?

Damihyph

Comment: Welcome! What version of CiviCRM and what CMS are you using, please? Also, can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Could you please try replicating this issue at http://demo.civicrm.org?  That will help determine if there's a bug in CiviCRM or an issue with your site, possibly in your CSS.

Answer (score 2):

`Tab` or `Tab with Table` display style creates a separate navigation tab to display and edit the values.

It will be shown as an extra tab in the Contact Summary Page unlike `Inline` which include the set of fields in the main contact `Add/Edit` form and Contact Summary screens.

[image]

Note: `Tab with Table` is recommended for customs data sets which allow multiple records.